# Full justify text in X column of tabularray

Tags: tabularx, justification, tabularray

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{colspec = {XX[5]}, width=\textwidth, hlines, vlines}
Description: & \lipsum[1]\\
\end{tblr}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|}
Description: & \lipsum[1]\\
\end{tabularx}


\end{document}
```

How to make `X-column` to fully justify its content like `tabularx` does (plus hyphenation if possible)?

Thank you.

Comment: The trick with `varwidth` environment (as in my other question on `itemize` in `tabularray`) solves the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/69

The `j` alignment is one of the new features in the upcoming release `2021N`. And it is already included in the package file you downloaded yesterday:

https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/raw/main/tabularray.sty

I will set `j` alignment as default in version `2022`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{colspec = {Q[j]X[5,j]}, width=\textwidth, hlines, vlines}
Description: & \lipsum[1]\\
\end{tblr}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|}
Description: & \lipsum[1]\\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

PS: If the cell text is very long, such as `\lipsum`, you need to use `measure=vbox` option and `varwidth` library.

[image]

Comment: Great, `j` column works! Thank you!